# Special Custom Checkmark in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

As I understand it, the `UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeCheckmark` appears when the row is tapped/untapped.

However, I would like to make an accessory that is always visible. Like a `Checkbox` or something of the sort. This is because i want to display additional information if the row is selected but if the `Checkbox` at the right end of the row is tapped, a tick should appear in it.

Sorry if I was not very clear. Please ask me for any clarifications.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that changes automatically when the user taps a row is the cell's highlighting. It's up to your code to toggle the checkbox accessory, if that's what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using button.Create a button in cell with unchecked checkbox image and when user click on this button change the image of the button to check.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your custom accessory view. In that view you add two UIImageView, and give a tag for the checkbox.

On create:

```
#define CHECKBOX_TAG 123

UIView *customAccessoryView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)] autorelease];
UIImageView *otherInfo = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)] autorelease];
UIImageView *checkbox = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 30, 30)] autorelease];
checkbox.tag = CHECKBOX_TAG;
[customAccessoryView addSubview:otherInfo];
[customAccessoryView addSubview:checkbox];
cell.accessoryView = customAccessoryView;
```

On display, if selected, set the checkbox hidden to NO:

```
UIImageView *checkbox = [cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:CHECKBOX_TAG];
if(selected){
    checkbox.hidden = NO;
}else{
    checkbox.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `UIKit` use `accessoryType` property of a `UITableViewCell`.

```
@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellAccessoryType accessoryType
```

If you really want a custom one use `accessoryView`.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a button and add it to your *acceessoryView:* and use it like a check box...
this will resolve your problem